# How to rectify account activation error in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I'm trying to click on an email activation link so as to activate a user account after submitting a registration form but I keep getting this error: `The connection for this site is not secure; 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.`. I ought to be redirected to the dashboard. Account is successfully created since the new user appears in the database but clicking on the activation link sent to the email throws back an error. I'm following a tutorial though, but I can't figure out why the problem occurs.
url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>)/', views.account_activate, name='activate'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard')
]
```

templates

```
account-activation_email.html:

{% autoescape off %}
Great {{ user.user_name }}!
Please click on the link below to activate your account
https://{{ domain }}{% url 'account:activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}

register.html

<form class="account-form p-4 rounded col-lg-10 mx-auto" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <h3 class="mb-2 font-weight-bold">Create an account</h3>
                                <p class="mb-4">Sign Up</p>
                                <label>{{ form.user_name.label }}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.user_name }}
                                <label>{{ form.email.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.email }}
                                <label>{{ form.company.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.company }}
                                <label>{{ form.license_number.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.license_number }}
                                <label>{{ form.state.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.state }}
                                <label>{{ form.city.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.city }}
                                <label>{{ form.address.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.address }}
                                <label>{{ form.postcode.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.postcode }}
                                <label>{{ form.phone_number.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.phone_number }}
                                <label>{{ form.password.label}}<span class="text-muted mb-4">
                                        </span></label>
                                 <small class="form-text text-muted mb-4 small">
                                    At least 8 characters and 1 digit
                                </small>
                                {{ form.password }}
                                <label>{{ form.password2.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.password2 }}
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block py-2 mb-4 mt-5 fw500 w-100" type="submit">Register</button>
                                <p class="text-center">
                                    <a>Already have an account?</a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
```

views.py

```
def account_register(request):
 #   if request.user.is_authenticated:
 #       return redirect('account:dashboard')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        registerForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registerForm.is_valid():
            user = registerForm.save(commit=False)
            user.email = registerForm.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(registerForm.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate your Account'
            message = render_to_string('account/registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject=subject, message=message)
            return HttpResponse('registered succesfully and activation sent')
    else:
        registerForm = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/registration/register.html', {'form': registerForm})


def account_activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = UserBase.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, user.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('account:dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account/registration/activation_invalid.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found out that the error occurs because I was using https instead of http, since I'm using a local server.